# Can UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization() be called more than once?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, unusernotificationcenter, unusernotification

Can UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization() be called more than once?

- Can I invoke upon every application launch?
- Can I invoke it again after the user has granted notification permissions?
- If not, why not?

Answer (score 5):

Answer: yes and no.

- You can call it more than once **ever**, but you cannot call it more than once **concurrently** or else all but one of the concurrent requests will fail without an error (i.e. `granted = false` but `error = nil`). Concurrent requests can happen if your app logic has multiple events that can trigger an authorization request, as opposed to the simple happy path of doing it once inside appDidFinishLaunching.
- Worse, concurrent requests will also trigger the notification permissions to **become turned off even though the user had already authorized them during a previous app run**. The bug report for such a scenario will look like this: "APN Permissions are Turning Themselves Off." Which, like all bugs, seems impossible at first.